# not able to get the result using date function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to check the condition using query

```
select min(date_format(date(time_stamp),'%Y-%m-%d'))as time_stamp,
       'FN' period,
       null count  ,
       null sheetno,
       if (count(min(date_format(date(time_stamp),'%Y-%m-%d')))=1 ,200,0) as amount  
from omr_verification
```

I want to calculate if time_stamp is avilable means amount=200 else 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use if condition or case in select.

```
select min(date_format(date(time_stamp),'%Y-%m-%d'))as time_stamp,
   'FN' period,
   null count  ,
   null sheetno,
   if (time_stamp !='' ,200,0) as amount  from omr_verification
```

Comment: ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Comment: Adding **if(time_stamp='',200,0) as amount** returns this error for you?

Comment: you misplaced , after amount

Comment: sorry for that, I have edited. You have to check whether time_stamp is empty or not, If not empty 200 should be the amount, else 0 right?